# How can I get the pid of a window that's currently opening?

Tags: window, xdotool

I know we can get the pid of the current window with `xdotool` with the command:

```
xdotool getactivewindow
```

However, that helps only with current opened windows... I'd like to find a way of getting the pid of a window that I'm currently opening, something like the following:

```
command-to-get-pid-of-process-that-is-opening-now "$(firefox https://www.google.com)"
```

I know that I could use `sleep` and wait a random time for the process to open and then use `xdotool getactivewindow`. But that doesn't look like an ideal solution. How can I get the pid of a window that I'm just opening?

Answer (score 2):

```
firefox https://www.google.com & MYPID=$!
```

will store the pid of the process you just launched in a variable `MYPID`.

However, don't hold your breath.

New windows are not necessarily associated with the command you ran. In the case of Firefox, the command may eventually communicate with an already running instance. The process for which you determined the pid will soon disappear.

You may want to, in a new question, ask about what you really want to achieve (*Problem X*). Other approaches than finding the pid of a window that you are about to launch (*Problem Y*, the current question) may be needed.